# Jquery Dialog box working only for the first link?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#headings_help").click(function(){
$("#box").dialog({

    title: 'Heading and Subheading IDs',
    width: 700,
    height:300,
    modal:true,
    resizable:false,
    buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Close',
      click: function(){
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
    }
    ]

    });
    });


});
</script>
```

For the above `javascript`, say you have this inline element as part of your form:

```
Help<a id='headings_help' ><img src='questionmark.png' border='0' /></a>
```

Say the above questionmark is there at multiple places on the webpage, the `jquery` code is only going to work for the first instance of the questionmark link. It is not going to work for other questionmarks on the same page.

Comment: When you do a question/answer like this, you should not include the answer in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
change this
Help<a class='headings_help' ><img src='questionmark.png' border='0' /></a>
and then
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".headings_help").click(function(){
$("#box").dialog({

    title: 'Heading and Subheading IDs',
    width: 700,
    height:300,
    modal:true,
    resizable:false,
    buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Close',
      click: function(){
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
    }
    ]

    });
    });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not use the id, it is to use a common class.

IDs are singular, they are not meant to repeat on the page.

So change the ids to a class

```
<a class='headings_help' ><img src='questionmark.png' border='0' /></a>
```

change the selector to use a class

```
$(".headings_help").on("click, function(){...});
```

Comment: multiple forms can have the same id elements in it, the forms names must be different but the id elements in it can be same.

Comment: @srinivas - The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Comment: @srinivas that is not correct, run the code through an HTML validator.

Comment: hmm Ok I got it, but it worked for me, hence I posted, noted the mistake. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: @srinivas Dementic is right. In case you or someone else would want to automate testing on your website (let's say they would like that), ids would be the MAIN concern. And that is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 apply same css class to all links 

 then use 

 $(".className").click(function(){
      .........
})
```

we can not use ont id to morethan one element.when you want to apply an event to morethan one elements then apply a css class to all and then use.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get all the links that have an image with `src` `questionmark.png`
var $Links = $.map($('a img[src="questionmark.png"]'), function () {
    return $(this).parent(); // return the parent
});

// Apply click for each of the links
$Links.click(function () {
    // Do your stuff here.
});
```

Comment: This is a bad way to do it, But oh well. I think you should listen to all the guys telling you to add a class and not id.